# What are the files from the 'make' of git that I actually need to run git?

Tags: linux, git, makefile, portable-executable

I'm trying to "portablize" git, so I want to send the required executables from the make process of git to my hosted web server. Can I do that? Do you think the executables will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I do it is to:

- get all Git dependencies ([as listed in this Solaris package site](http://www.sunfreeware.com/programlistsparc10.html#git), but this works for any Unix platform)
- compile those dependencies with `--prefix=/home/myuser` and install them in the `usr/local/lib` of my home directory
- then compile Git (still avoiding any reference to a system path like /usr/local/lib, but only using the lib and include within my homedir)
- and install Git in the /home/myuser/git directory

I can then copy only `/home/myuser/git` and `/home/myuser/usr/local` (and `$prefix/libexec/git-core` as [Jakub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) mentions in the comments) to any other similar server, knowing it will work in isolation from any existing system libraries.

Comment: That will work with built-in commands, but some commands are external scripts / programs and have to be copied separately from `$prefix/libexec/git-core/` (including e.g. `git stash`, `git pull` (but not `git fetch`), `git bisect`, etc.)

Comment: how do you mean copied separately?

Comment: @jphenow: it is just a permission issue (like `chmod 755` the copied binaries)? Or a `PATH` issue? (remember to set a similar set of environment variable when using that distribution on the remote server. `/usr/local/lib` shouldn't be part of the `PATH`)

Comment: could be because i did ./configure &make&make install on a 64 then tried running on a 32.... how do i cross compile git?

Comment: @jphenow: that is probably the cause of the execution issue: I always deploy on "similar" platform.

Comment: I'll have to find out what the shared servers on GoDaddy are running and try it again